Do souls live eternally in hell and in heaven?
I was recently having a discussion with my daughter in law about the eternity of the soul. She disagreed with me on how long souls lasted. She said if we are saved that we will live forever in Heaven with God/Jesus, but somehow the souls who go to hell/lake of fire will not live forever?
I disagree, but wanted to see what other people had to say, based on their scriptural evidence.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Lisa. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. To ensure your question remains open and can be effectively addressed using hermeneutical methods, please include a specific verse. This addition will provide a foundation for applying hermeneutical approaches.

Hello Lisa - there is only one Bible passage that discusses people going into the lake of fire which is Rev 20:8, 14, 15.  If you base your question upon this verse, it will not be deleted.  Do you wish to modify the question or would you like me to edit it for you?

I disagree as well. However you will need to base your question on a particular text of scripture to have your question answered on this, an hermeneutic site where we need some text to analyse. Jesus used the term 'Gehenna' and you might wish to ask about that. Or ask about 2 Thessalonians 1:9 Who shall be punished with everlasting destruction from the presence of the Lord, and from the glory of his power;, perhaps. Welcome to SE-BH.
